How to remove filter for unrelated dimension table?
I have two fact tables: fact_ProductionBOM and fact_SalesItemLedger. The two fact tables share one conformed dimensions - dim_FinishedItem.
The fact_ProductionBOM table has an additional relationship to dim_Component and fact_SalesItemLedger has an additional relationship to dim_Customer.
I need to write a DAX measure which calculates the maximum BOM Quantity of a given component?
The resulting table visualization should include the following fields:

'dim_Customer'[CustomerNo]
'dim_FinishedItem'[ItemNo]
'dim_Component[ComponentItemNo]
Sum('fact_SalesItemLedger'[ShippedQuantity])
Measure which calculates the max of 'fact_ProductionBOM'[BOMQuantity] per each combination of 'dim_FinishedItem'[ItemNo] and 'dim_Component[ComponentItemNo]

The issue I'm facing is that because dim_Customer and dim_Component are not conformed across both fact tables, I get duplication in the table.
How can I write the measure to accommodate for this?
I've tried the following:

Using CALCULATE to return the max and imposing ALL('dim_Customer').
Using CALCULATE to return the max and imposing REMOVEFILTERS('dim_Customer')

However with either option, I still get duplication of customers and components in my final table.

To help us replicate this, can you please provide a picture of your model schema, some tables of example data, and a table of expected output?
